# How many times do I have to play New Game+ to be able to unlock all blacksmith plans?

Tags: rogue-legacy

According to [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/122214/3062), new blacksmith plans are unlocked in New Game+. I know once you beat NG+, you move on to NG++, and so on.

What's the maximum "+" I need to be able to unlock all blacksmithing plans?

Comment: I've gotten Dragon equipment, which is the second last column, on NG+.

Comment: I'm curious if stacking Curse runes can impact the answer, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NG+ is all you need.  Beating the game any more than once is not neccessary to obtain all the equipment.
I got every blueprint discovered before getting to NG++.
If blueprints stop appearing in random chests, you need to look for rooms with 2 tougher versions of normal enemies and defeat them for a special chest to appear in the middle of the room which usually has the higher level blueprints.  For examples, there's a room with 2 warlocks dressed in black named Amon and Barbatos.  There's another room with 2 huge yellow skeletons.  There's also one room with a large lance knight named Botis.  Etc.

Answer (score 1):

From stacking 5 curse runes before going to NG+,  I was able to get all the armor except for:

-all armor in the last column

-2 pieces in the second to last column.  I keep farming but am not able to get any other armor pieces.

I don't think one could get all that armor without stacking curse rooms though before going to NG+.